# Как имея домен настроить надежную отправку почты через сторонний smtp сервер?

Tags: email, smtp

Есть домен mydomen.ru .
Есть выделенный сервер где сайт.
Нужно подтверждать регистрацию пользователей и отправлять напоминание пароля на почту. И чтобы пользователю письмо приходило с ящика того же домена что и сайт.

Сайт подключается к smtp серверу например mail.nic.ru по порту 2525, передаёт 
почтовый ящик пароль к нему и тип шифрования (tls). Дальше сервер должен отправить письмо уже адресату.

Пробовал такие варианты:

1. Google - почта(smtp.gmail.com). Медленно отправляет письма(5-20 секунд ожидания). Иногда не доходит.
2. nic.ru - mail.nic.ru (платный стоит 160 рублей в месяц) работает только по порту 2525 или 587, по 25 не отвечает. Медленно отправляет (5-20 секунд), 10% писем не приходит.
3. Запустить свой smtp сервер. Письма отправляются за 1 секунду. Но здесь нужно чтобы провайдер который управляет этим сервером разместил ptr запись для своего ip адреса, иначе письма не приходят спам фильтр. А провайдер этого делать не хочет.

1) Как в этих условиях сделать так, чтобы соединение и передача smtp серверу письма на отправку скриптами сайта выполнялась за 1 секунду, как в большинстве сайтов?

2) Чтобы письма всегда доставлялись, а не случайным образом? Есть ли smtp сервера внешние с надежной отправкой писем и быстрые.

Comment: Можете также попробовать [почту для домена яндекса](https://pdd.yandex.ru)  (smtp.yandex.ru)

Comment: *А провайдер этого делать не хочет* — логичный совет: смените провайдера.